# How to generate this specific list in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to generate this array of zeros in some type of a loop unless there is another method. The first few lines below output just the way I want.

I cannot reproduce this in a loop as the append function doesn't append like I think it will. Any suggestions please?

Edit: Of course I get a -1 for asking a question. Does every question on here have to be alien level intelligence?

```py
import numpy as np

# This is how I want t_in to be like, 64 zeros in a nested list.
t_in = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
print(t_in) # Looks good.
print("\n")

# This is my non working attempt to do it in a list.
t_in = np.array([])
for i in range(0, 64):
    np.append(t_in, [0])

print(t_in) # Not the same :(
```

Comment: Just use: t_in = np.zeros((1, 64))

Comment: Or if you really want to so this in a loop use: t_in = np.append(t_in, [0])

Comment: does it *have* to be in a loop? because looping is just about the worst thing to do while working with numpy.

Comment: Thanks @SeanSdahl. I can't believe a function like np.zeros() exists! lol

Comment: Thank @Paritosh Singh, tip received!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why make it more complicated than it actually is.
Just use the tools provided by numpy:

```
t_in = np.zeros((1, 64))
```

It is faster than plain python and cleaner to read.

Answer (score 2):

Does this solve your problem?

```py
>>> t_in = [0 for _ in range(64)]
>>> t_in
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> t_in = [t_in]
>>> t_in
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>>
```

Not familiar with `numpy`, maybe there is a better way.

Comment: It is easier to just use t_in = np.zeros((1, 64))

Comment: Why not `t_in = [[0 for _ in range(64)]]`

Comment: np is faster than plain python

Comment: @splash58 merely for clarity. Why would you need a array full of zeros to start with? A generator is probably more appropriate whatever the case might be. As others pointed out already, if the OP is using `numpy` there are better ways anyway.

Comment: I don't need it at all

Comment: All, very useful. Thanks.

Comment: This is indeed a solution that works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why use a loop? Just take advantage of how lists work¹

```
>>> t_in = [[0] * 64]
>>> t_in
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0]]
```

This is the fastest² approach even compared to `np.zeros`

```
>>> timeit('[[0]*64]')
1.5534695980022661
>>> timeit('[0 for _ in range(64)]')
10.40757498399762
>>> timeit('numpy.zeros((1, 64))', 'import numpy')
1.732236907002516
>>> #just to compare... let's make np.zeros into a list so each return the same thing.
```

¹That said this approach creates shallow copies of the list items so they will all be the same object although this is irrelevant in this situation.

²If you ultimately need an array then `np.zeros` is the fastest but if you only need a list then the list mul option is best.

Comment: Edited with more explination and comparison please see. Also if this or any of the other answers have adequately answered your question then please mark it with the big checkmark to the left of the answer!

Comment: but the numpy way only took longer because you timed the import of numpy as well. If you need numpy anyway the numpy way is faster. And furthermore the array returned by numpy is much more efficient to work with.

Comment: No I also timed using lambdas as well, see https://repl.it/languages/python3. It's faster. Plus `timeit` only times the execution of the statement not the setup. Refer to my note at the end as `np.zeros` is faster than the list mul approach when you need an array but if you need a list then this is.